# jquery ajax problem?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
 <form class="follow-form" method="post" action="listen.php">
    <input name="followID" value="123456" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="btn follow" title="123456">
        <i></i><span>follow</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

javascript file:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
         /* fetch elements and stop form event */
         $("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {
          /* stop event */
          e.preventDefault();
          /* "on request" */
          $(this).find('i').addClass('active');
          /* send ajax request */
          $.post('listen.php', {
           followID: $(this).find('input').val()
          }, function () {
           /* find and hide button, create element */
           $(e.currentTarget)
             .find('button').hide()
             .after('<span class="following"><span></span>Following!</span>');
          });
         });
        });
```

i wanted to know what kind of process would go in the listen.php via ajax, i know its a mysql statement, but then what after!!

what it deos is : when you click the follow button, this sends the ajax request to listen.php and then if successfull it transfroms into following, showing that you followed the user

thanks i have been up all night

Comment: It depends what you want to do after you've run your MySQL statement. Do you want to display something?

Comment: at the button of the javascript file it says .after <span.... thats what happens when the listen.php finshes..!! if you get what i mean

Comment: A good sleep will definitely clear your mind.

Comment: lool, i promised myself i have to finsh this before i sleep, its coursework for my university, i need show a jquery working script!! thanks for the advice though

Comment: I'm still unclear to what you want to do after your AJAX call is complete, can you be a bit more clear? And yes, you should get some sleep.

Comment: "and then if successfull it transfroms into following" but nowhere are you checking if it is successful... you just unconditionally displaying "following." And you'll probably want a SQL insert and then an echo out saying whether or not it was successful.  Get some sleep....

Comment: basically when i click the follow button(as shown on the html) it takes me straight to listen.php,but the code is meant to just chnage from a button to a text saying "following", without me going to listen.php.....

Comment: @guttsy exactly what i wanted, even unconditionally it takes me to a blank listen.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there really isn't anything wrong with the code you have here. I've set up a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWGse/)** to test it, and it works fine. The only problem, and it shouldn't affect whether the `submit` event is captured by the event handler, is that the HTML fragment you're trying to insert after the button is invalid - you've got your opening and closing tags mixed up. This is the code I have after that minor edit:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("form.follow-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).find('i').addClass('active');

        $.post('/ajax_html_echo/', {
            followID: $(this).find('input').val()
        }, function() {
            $(e.currentTarget).find('button').hide().after('<span class="following">Following!</span>');
        });
    });
});
```

Other than that, it works fine - that is, assuming you want the `following` span to display no matter what the outcome of the ajax request is.

Comment: thank you very much, but where would i put the mysql statments

Comment: @getaway You have to do that in `listen.php`